# Use JSON data outside of initial .ajax call - Access leftover JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter, jquery-masonry

This is partly an extension to a [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150228/codeigniter-ajax-response-contains-data-but-output-is-undefined) of mine:

I can now successfully returned JSON data from my CI controller which **returns:**

```
{"results":[{"id":"1","Source":"My Source","Title":"My Title". . . .
```

The **Controller:**

```
function outputAjax()
{
    $this->load->model('my_model');
    $data['results'] = $this->site_model->getInfo();
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
}
```

This is my current script I am using to retrieve the `.ajax` request:

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {    
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'http://localhost/project/index.php/controller/outputAjax',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data) 
                {   
                    var limit = 19; //how many json objects are needed initially
                    var arr = []; // item.id of objects that have been used 
                    $.each(data.results, function(index,item)
                    {
                        if (index > limit) return false; // gets required initial json objects
                        arr.push(item.id); // stores used json objects id's

                        // whole bunch of checks on item.id , item.Title, item.Description, etc...

                        $("#masonry-content").append('<div class="item" ' + item.id + item.Title + ' ... </div>');
                    });
```

As the above code shows, I am currently taking the first 20 objects of JSON data and appending them to the page container. This works fine but..

**The issue** I am having is that I would like to update the content in those 20 divs that have been appended to the page on a `time interval` with other objects of the initially returned JSON data. I feel like the best way to do this is to layout the div's statically on the page since there will always be the same amount and then just update the data in those divs accordingly.

**My question** is how can I still access the returned JSON data once outside the scope of the initial .ajax call.

**For example:** If I would leave the script setup the way it is, after I make the initial `.ajax` call and `append()` the content to the container with the first 20 JSON data objects ( `item` ). How do I access the rest of the objects in the JSON data?

I already assumed my best bet to keep track of the objects returned was to store the item.id of each object in an array `arr[ ]` *Please correct me if this does not make sense or their is a much easier way.* But, I still don't know how to access the leftover JSON data *objects*?

I feel as though I am missing something obvious such as making my javascript more *object oriented* would help so then I could access each json object individually and perform different functions on it but I feel as though I may be lost a little.

Comment: Would a possible solution be to make each JSON object returned a Javascript object that can take the parameters of the returned JSON data such as (id, title, desc, link ... )?

Comment: can you not just assign data.results to a variable declared at the scope holding your updating logic?

Comment: @ScottEvernden Unless I am misunderstanding, data.results is not accessible outside of the .ajax request. Wouldn't it be considered bad practice to have the majority of my code inside `.ajax { }` so it could be accessed. Appreciate the help!

Comment: To clarify, I will not be updating the contents in all of the divs on the page at the same time, Will be using a time interval to update individual divs, after a complete initial load of all divs. (ex: update each div every 5 seconds or so with a new JSON object's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just store your json in a global variable, and loop through the items as you need them, starting with 20 by calling `setDivs(20)` after successfully loading the json.

```
// Declaration of global variables
data = ''; // JSON data will be stored here
myurl = 'http://localhost/project/index.php/controller/outputAjax';
index = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON(myurl, function (JSON) { data = JSON; setDivs(20); });
    $('#next20').click(function() { setDivs(20); });
});

function setDivs(num) {
    $("#masonry-content").empty();
    for (var i = index ; i < index + num -1; i++) {
        $("#masonry-content").append('<div class="item" ' + data["results"][i].id + data["results"][i].Title + ' ... </div>');
    }
    index += num;
}
```

I've also added code which will update your `#masonry-content` element with the next 20 divs from the json object upon clicking a `#next20` element on the page.

Of course, I've no idea if your `#masonry-content` element is empty to begin with.  If it's not, then add something like a `<div id="json-data"></div>` inside your `#masonry-content` element, and update the above code accordingly by replacing both instances of `$('#masonry-content")` with `$('#json-data')`

If `data["results"][i]` doesn't work, maybe try `data.results[i]`.

If you are using Chrome, pull up the console (CTRL+SHIFT+J) and type `data` and press enter.  If the JSON was successfully loaded, you should be able to explore the tree of the data object.  Then you can play around with it in the console, trying `data["results"]`, `data.results` etc. and keep working your way down (i.e. try `data["results"][0]` and verify that it pulls the first item).

**Update:**

Here's a working [JSON/AJAX Ticker](http://ticker.weisser.co/) example which randomly swaps items every 4.5 seconds.  It was built in response to twhyler's [follow-up question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288513/track-which-json-objects-have-been-output/14299172#14299172).

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I'm gonna add what you have mentioned and a few other ideas I have and report back shortly. Side-note: It wouldn't be considered bad practice to have JSON data in global right? Since it's fully available in the browser anyway I would assume it would be ok. Would you agree?

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it's helpful.  And yes, I have a handful of applications with thousands of daily users that utilize JSON just like that - should be fine because you're off-loading the data to the user's browser letting the client do all the "heavy" lifting. =P

Comment: data.results[i].Id worked fine. Your for loop and getJSON worked as well. Thanks! Question, I would still like to know which id's of the JSON data have been output. How would I go about tracking this? I know I can use `array.push();` to add the items to the array but how would I make this array available globally while getting this information from inside the function setDivs(); Thanks!

Comment: Since I am only going to be updating the individual div's content at a time-interval and don't want to output a JSON item that has already been output and I would need to know which div to update via the i value or the id used in each div. I think my course of action would be to create another function updateDiv() that would get passed these arguments. Any advice or help with that? Thanks for all your help so far, really helped me understand what needed to be done so far.

Comment: @Twhyler If you want an array available globally, you can add `seen = new Array();` right after you declare `data = '';`.  Then, use   `seen.push(i);` to store the index of seen items, or use `seen.push(data.results[i].id);` if you would rather store the ID.  

Your other question is a good one as well, and I'd suggest creating a new StackOverflow post, and link to it from here.  It would be easier to help knowing the big-picture of your project.  Are you setting up pagination?  Tom Bird's suggestion about setting up a template is also a good one, and I can provide a slick example.

Comment: Thanks for the help again, works fine. I was going to post a new question but since I am still learning, figured doing it as much on my own would help with that process, which it definitely has. I have gotten a good bit farther but decided it was time to post a new question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288513/track-which-json-objects-have-been-output) If you could take a quick look. I am going to hold of on using a template which I agree would help in the long run. I would love to see your "slick" example though for future reference. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could, simply declare a variable outside of your ajax call then inside your ajax function the update the variables value to the json object in its entirety. See below I named the variable `data`

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {

         var data = '';

            $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'http://localhost/project/index.php/controller/outputAjax',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data) 
                {   

                    data = data;

                    });
```

However I would personally create a template div of how you want an individual element to appear and then just fill in the data rather than trying to search specific tags in 20 places and then replacing that data with new data. I think it would be much easier and efficient to basically empty `$("#masonry-content").empty();` Then refill it with the new elements using append or something like that.