# Track which JSON objects have been output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm outputting 20 or so JSON objects randomly by setting the index to a `randomNumber()` initially when the page is loaded.

I'm refreshing each JSON object individually that has already been output on a timeInterval.
To keep track of which JSON items have been output I am storing the index of each item into an array via `arrUsed.push[index]`

Now trying to write the function that will `update()` each JSON objects individually and am currently stuck on how I can update the each div with the information from a new JSON object that has not already been output (pushed to the `arrUsed[]`).

Here's the function I have so far:

```
function reloadItems() {
    var itemTotal = $('div.item').length; // Total number of items loaded initially
    var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*301) //returns number 
    index = randomNumber; // Sets index to be used in JSON data to random number
}
```

The array that contains the already output index's is declared globally: `arrUsed = [];` Each item that is output initially when the page load is being stored to the array fine, so that part is covered. It's a matter of choosing a random JSON object, checking to ensure it is not in the array/not been output already, and then updating the div on the page.

Here's the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264647/use-json-data-outside-of-initial-ajax-call-access-leftover-json-data/14265131#comment19826534_14265131) that has led me to this point

Comment: why not just put all the content in DOM and hide all but 20, then display others in timer?

Comment: Hmm didn't think of that option at all. Since I have about 300 json objects to start and it will become about 600 I would assume bad practice / performance issues from outputting 300-600 divs hidden and then displaying them as needed... Am i understanding what you are referencing?

Comment: FYI - no such thing as a `JSON object` ..JSON is a string data format

Comment: Ok thanks, when I said Object I was meaning each individual piece of JSON data, so I guess JSON array index would be the proper term? Care to answer the question I asked you in the comment above?

Comment: is this what you are trying to do?  http://jsfiddle.net/BQkFB/

Comment: Yes almost exactly, except I am trying to update them individually instead of all at once as in your example. The part where you are checking for the item already being output is correct though. Thanks for that. In your example, assuming after it runs through the array of items available to output, it will restart and run through the array again?

Comment: try this version  http://jsfiddle.net/BQkFB/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example of a JSON/AJAX Ticker:

- **http://ticker.weisser.co/**

Per twhyler's specification, it randomly swaps an item every 4.5 seconds, keeping track of ones that have already been seen.  Once they've all been seen, it starts over again:

[image: JSON/AJAX Ticker]

Code Files:

- **[default.html](http://ticker.weisser.co/default.html)** (Main Program)
- **[template.html](http://ticker.weisser.co/template.html)** (Product Template)
- **[UK.top.20.html](http://ticker.weisser.co/UK.top.20.html)** (JSON Data)
- **[ticker.js](http://ticker.weisser.co/ticker.js)** (jQuery)
- **[ticker.css](http://ticker.weisser.co/ticker.css)** (Style Sheet)

First, we should store template.html in our global `template` variable and fire the `getJson()` function:

```
template = '';
....
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('template.html', function(html) { template = html; getJson(); });
});
```

Then, we'll store the JSON into our `data` variable and fire the `initialize()` function:

```
data = ''; // JSON data will be stored here
myurl = 'UK.top.20.html';
....
function getJson() { 
$.getJSON(myurl, function (JSON) { data = JSON; initialize(); });
}
```

Here, we'll call the `load()` function 3 times to populate our 3 product div's with data right away.  Then we set `i` back to `2` (that's so it will change the 3rd DIV first), and schedule `tick()` to fire in 4.5 seconds:

```
tick_time = 4500;
....
function initialize() { // Start with the first 3
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) { load(); }
i = 2;
setTimeout('tick()', tick_time);
}
```

Before we explain the `load()` function, let's talk about `String.prototype.f' at the bottom of the script:

```
String.prototype.f = function () { var args = arguments; return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function (m, n) { return args[n]; }); };
```

This function works similar to `String.Format(formatstring, arg1, arg2, arg3...)` in C# or `sprintf($formatstring, arg1, arg2, arg3...)` in PHP.  Here's an example:

```
formatstring = 'Roses are {0}, Violets are {1}, String.Format {2} and so do {3}!';
result = formatstring.f('red', 'blue', 'rocks', 'you');
alert(result);
```

So as you can see, this `String.prototype.f` function comes in very handy!

The first thing the `load()` function will do is set `rid = randomId();`.  Let's take a look at the `randomId()` function next.  The first thing it does is get a number from 1-20 (based on the length of our JSON data).  Then, it checks to see if our `seen` array is the same size as our JSON data, and if it is - it sets it back to 0.  Next it makes sure that our `rid` hasn't been seen recently, and if it has, the function recursively calls itself again till it gets a unique random id.  Otherwise, we store the `rid` in our `seen` array and return the value.

```
function randomId() {
rid = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.results.length);
if (seen.length == data.results.length) { seen.length = 0; }
if ($.inArray(rid, seen) == -1) {
    seen.push(rid);
    return rid;
} else { return randomId(); }
}
```

Next in our `load()` function after getting that random ID, we setup `item` and `plat` as convenient shortcuts.  `plat_html` is a temporary storage place for the Platform elements.  The for-loop looks at all the Platform data in our JSON and uses our String.Format function to fill our plat_html string.

Finally, we allow the current value of i (which is global) determine which `#product_` gets updated, and `template.f` fills our template with JSON data which is done with a smooth jQuery animation thanks to `.fadeIn()`.

```
function load() {
rid = randomId();
item = data.results[rid];
plat = item.Platform;
plat_html = '';
for (var j = 0; j < plat.length; j++) {
    plat_html += plat_fmt.f(
        plat[j].Hardware, 
        plat[j].Market
    );
}
$('#product_' + i).html(
    template.f(
        item.Image, 
        item.id, 
        item.AgeRating,
        item.WikiUrl,
        item.Title,
        item.Source,
        item.Genre,
        plat_html
    )
).fadeIn();
}
```

Lastly, let's take a look at the recursive `tick()` function.  It begins by incrementing our global `i` variable and setting it back to 1 when it reaches 4.  Then we perform an animated `fadeOut()` on our `#product_` element and wait till it's finished till we call `load()` again.  Then, it schedules itself to run again in another 4.5 seconds.

```
function tick() {
i++; if (i == 4) { i = 1; }
$('#product_' + i).fadeOut(function() { load(); });
setTimeout('tick()', tick_time);
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Wow... Thank you so much. That's one of the most detailed answers I have ever seen. Will take some time to look at it all and work it into my app but it looks perfect. Thanks!!

Comment: Great - I hope it's helpful. =P It was a fun project to tackle.  Let me know how it turns out!  I have some ideas about how to rewrite the randomId function.  The way it is right now, it could be mildly taxing on a user's computer when there are hundreds of items.  Basically it should be re-written to keep a another array of unseen items as well (like a queue).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.inArray()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
$.inArray(indexInQuestion, arrUsed);
```

It will return `-1` if the element is not in the array, so you will know wether `indexInQuestion` was already added to `arrUsed`.